# Javascript Webcam is not working in SWT Browser

Tags: browser, swt

I want to open a website inside a SWT Browser.
This is working as expected. But now I would like to use a webcam.
If I try the same in my Chrome browser, it´s working (first I got a message so I can use the webcam...)

[image]

Here my code for the SWT Browser:

```java
public class SWTBrowser {

    private static Display display;
    private static Shell shell;

    /**
     * Launch
     */
    public static final void launch() {
        display = new Display();

        shell = new Shell(display);
        Rectangle clientArea = display.getClientArea();

        shell.setSize(clientArea.width, clientArea.height);

        shell.setLocation(0, 0);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();
        gridLayout.numColumns = 3;
        gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
        gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
        shell.setFullScreen(false);

        shell.setLayout(gridLayout);
        
        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.NONE);
        browser.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

        GridData data = new GridData();
        data.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        data.verticalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
        data.horizontalSpan = 3;
        data.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
        data.grabExcessVerticalSpace = true;
        data.widthHint = clientArea.width;
        data.heightHint = clientArea.height;
        browser.setLayoutData(data);

        shell.open();
        browser.setUrl("http://localhost:" + Constants.SERVER_PORT + "/portal/dashboard.jsf");

        
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch())
                display.sleep();
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    //////////////////////
    //// Getter + Setter
    //////////////////////

    public static Display getDisplay() {
        return display;
    }

    public static void setDisplay(Display display) {
        SWTBrowser.display = display;
    }

    public static Shell getShell() {
        return shell;
    }

    public static void setShell(Shell shell) {
        SWTBrowser.shell = shell;
    }
```

I´m using also this in my POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</artifactId>
    <version>3.120.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Probably something similar to the problem described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=562179)

Comment: hm, maybe... but I´m not sure what I need to fix it?

Comment: Any further idea?